# Not able to upload pre-trained model to AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, random-forest, joblib, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have trained a random forest classifier and stored the model as a joblib file on google storage. The ai-platform is giving an error when a version is created using scikit-learn framework with this model.joblib file. 
The error goes like -:

```html
Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Could not load the model: /tmp/model/a0001/model.joblib. 0. (Error code: 0)"
```

The model is 283Mb - well within the allowed size limit.

Answer (score 1):

That error, as you can see in the [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/troubleshooting), usually means the wrong library was used to export the model. To correct this, re-export the model using the correct library.

Remember that the joblib library in the AI Platform is imported doing:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

You have an example of how to export it [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/using-pipelines-for-preprocessing#export_your_model).

Comment: I have imported joblib as import joblib.
sklearn.externals joblib package was showing a warning that it may get deprecated so i use the direct import - import joblib

Comment: Tried using sklearn.externals import joblib. It still gives the same error.
ERROR:
Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Could not load the model: /tmp/model/0001/model.joblib. 0. (Error code: 0)"

Comment: If the joblib library still gives you problems, try using the pickle library and save it as a model.pkl.

Comment: same issue but the other way round. joblib works but pkl doesn't. Also, more than 350MB gives me a model too big error. @aemon4 did you manage to solve it?